# No package pgadmin3 available

Tags: software-installation, yum, postgresql

I'm running CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

I'm trying to install

`sudo yum install pgadmin3`

I keep getting

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * extras: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
base                                                                                          | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00     
No package pgadmin3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

---

I've also tried `sudo yum update`

run `sudo yum install pgadmin3` again - still got the same result ! :(

Any hints/suggestions will be much appreciated !

Comment: Take a look at here: http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/download/rpm.php

Answer (score 1):

`yum list pgadmin*` into one of my CentOS 6.7(final) this is what I find :

```
Available Packages
pgadmin3.x86_64                             1.20.0-1.el6                  epel  
pgadmin3_91.x86_64                          1.20.0-3.rhel6                pgdg91
pgadmin3_91-debuginfo.x86_64                1.20.0-3.rhel6                pgdg91
pgadmin3_91-docs.x86_64                     1.20.0-3.rhel6                pgdg91
```

it seems that the package is available in `epel` repository and in `pgdg91` repository. You just need to add one them

I would proceed as follow :

```
# Adding pgdg repo
sudo rpm -Uvh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-6-i386/pgdg-centos91-9.1-4.noarch.rpm
# check if the package is now available
sudo yum list pgadmin*
# and in case it is, install it
```

Answer (score 1):

First you could try this instead:

```
sudo yum install pgadmin3_91
```

If you want to make sure you get the latest, you can go here and download the latest source code release which comes in the .tar.gz file extension:

http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/

Once you have downloaded the source code use the following commands to install pgAdmin.  In this example I'm using pgadmin3-1.10.3.tar.gz but substitute that with the version you choose.  Then:

```
mv pgadmin3-1.10.3.tar.gz /usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src
tar –zxvf pgadmin3-1.10.3.tar.gz
cd pgadmin3-1.10.3
./configure
make
make install
```

pgAdmin should now be available to access localhost database servers running on the same computer.  In order to configure your server to allow for remote user access of the database using pgAdmin, we will have to modify 2 configuration files. This site will show you how:

http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/6-advanced-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/14-how-to-install-pgadmin-and-configure-postgresql-server-to-accept-remote-connections.html